# Could monotone class theorem be applied to the proof of inequality (of probability)

Tags: probability-theory, monotone-class-theorem

I have 4 independent random variables: $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$. And I know for any measurable sets $S_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, S_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2$, I have

$$\Pr(X_1 \in S_1) \leq c\Pr(Y_1 \in S_1)$$

$$\Pr(X_2 \in S_2) \leq c\Pr(Y_2 \in S_2)$$

for some constant $c>1$.

By independence, I deduce that

$$\Pr((X_1,X_2) \in S_1 \times S_2) \leq c^2\Pr((Y_1,Y_2) \in S_1 \times S_2)$$

Now, the question is: does this property hold for all sets in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2)$?

We cannot use the monotone class theorem here, for this property does not hold for $\lambda$-system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that the set $S$ of finite **disjoint** unions of "rectangles" forms an algebra and use the monotone class theorem (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem) as opposed to Dynkins $\pi\lambda$ theorem about which you seem to be thinking.

EDIT: Second possibility: It is (at least for finite (positive) measures) not hard to see $(\mu +\nu)\otimes \gamma =\mu \otimes \gamma +\nu \otimes \gamma$, wher $\otimes$ denotes the product measure.

For a finite signed measure $\nu =\mu_1 -\mu_2$ with finite positive measures, it is thus easy to see that $\nu \otimes \gamma :=\mu_1\otimes \gamma -\mu_2\otimes\gamma$ is well-defined, independent of the decomposition chosen for $\nu$.

Now, if $\mu\leq \nu$ and $\gamma$ is a finite positive measure, we get $0\leq (\nu -\mu)\otimes \gamma$, which by linearity yields $\mu \otimes \gamma \leq \nu\otimes \gamma$.

A slight generalisation also shows $\gamma \otimes \mu \leq \gamma \otimes \nu$.

Now your assumptions are

$$
\mu_i \leq c \nu_i
$$
for $i \in \{1,2\}$, where the $\mu_i,\nu_i$ are the apropriate image measures. Now the above considerations imply your claim.

Comment: Thanks @PhoemueX ! Your first proof only uses the 3rd equation, while your second proof uses directly the 1st and 2nd equation and the independence. It seems to me that we can generalize the first proof to the case where Pr(X1∈S1)≤cPr(Y1∈S1)+d; while the second not.

Comment: @Sisyphuss: The generalisation to the "$+d$" case will not work, I think. The problem is that in the first step, we have to "lift" from rectangles to finite disjoint unions of rectangles. This only works smoothly if both sides of the inequality are additive. If you add an absolute constant, this will fail.

Comment: You are right. I was too excited to realize this simple fact. Anyway, thanks again!!